# Data alignment and zero-bits relation?

Tags: arm, alignment, relation, zero, bit

Reading through a paper for the ARM Cortex-M3 CPU I found this line confusing:

> The lowest 2 bits of the stack
>   pointers are always 0, which means
>   they are always word aligned

I have seen similar statements elsewhere. What is the logic behind some zero bits => some alignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the 2 LS bits are always zero then addresses can only be multiples of 4, i.e. addresses can only be:

```
Hex      Binary
xxxxxxx0 bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb0000
xxxxxxx4 bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb0100
xxxxxxx8 bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb1000
xxxxxxxc bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb1100
```

(If it helps, think of the equivalent in decimal - any number that ends in 00 is a multiple of 10^2 = 100).

Comment: Oh of course. Somehow I thought the pointers themselves were aligned when stored - not that they pointed to aligned data..